# Is there a way to get the nlargest items per group in dask?

Tags: pandas, grouping, dask, top-n

I have the following dataset:

```
location  category    percent
A         5           100.0
B         3           100.0
C         2            50.0
          4            13.0
D         2            75.0
          3            59.0
          4            13.0
          5             4.0
```

And I'm trying to get the nlargest items of category in dataframe grouped by location. i.e. If I want the top 2 largest percentages for each group the output should be:

```
location  category    percent
A         5           100.0
B         3           100.0
C         2            50.0
          4            13.0
D         2            75.0
          3            59.0
```

It looks like in pandas this is relatively straight forward using `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest` but dask doesn't have an `nlargest` function for groupby.  Have been playing around with `apply` but can't seem to get it to work properly.

`df.groupby(['location'].apply(lambda x: x['percent'].nlargest(2)).compute()`

But I just get the error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 8`

Comment: in your data set which one is the index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apply should work, but your syntax is a little off:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              Unnamed: 0 location category  percent
npartitions=1
                   int64   object    int64  float64
                     ...      ...      ...      ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 3 tasks

In [12]: df.groupby("location")["percent"].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2), meta=('x', 'f8')).compute()
Out[12]:
location
A         0    100.0
B         1    100.0
C         2     50.0
          3     13.0
D         4     75.0
          5     59.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

In pandas you'd have `.nlargest` and `.rank` as groupby methods which would let you do this without the apply:

```
In [21]: df1
Out[21]:
  location  category  percent
0        A         5    100.0
1        B         3    100.0
2        C         2     50.0
3        C         4     13.0
4        D         2     75.0
5        D         3     59.0
6        D         4     13.0
7        D         5      4.0

In [22]: df1.groupby("location")["percent"].nlargest(2)
Out[22]:
location
A         0    100.0
B         1    100.0
C         2     50.0
          3     13.0
D         4     75.0
          5     59.0
Name: percent, dtype: float64
```

[The dask documentation notes](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html#scope):

> Dask.dataframe covers a small but well-used portion of the pandas API.
>   This limitation is for two reasons:
>
> 1. The pandas API is huge
> 2. Some operations are genuinely hard to do in parallel (for example sort).

Comment: It could be that rank/cumcount would sit under cleverly parallelizable, so it might be worth making a feature request to dask to support these on the groupby. I think _maybe_ I implemented a faster path for nlargest in pandas (previously you had to use apply or slice on the rank).

Comment: Now I think about it, nlargest is much easier to parallelize than rank (especially if n is small), so that'll be why rank is not implemented in dask. I still think this could be a good dask feature request...

Comment: Thanks, to get category back in the final dataframe, would I merge results on the "location" column?

Comment: @whisperstream something like this? `df.groupby('location')[["category", "percent"]].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns=["percent"]), meta={"category": 'f8', "percent": 'f8'}).compute()`