# Dask: Groupby with nlargest automatically brings in index and doesn't allow reset_index()

Tags: grouping, dask, dask-distributed

I've been trying to get nlargest rows for a group by following method from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227874/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-nlargest-items-per-group-in-dask). The solution to the question is correct up to a point.

In this example, I groupby column `A` and want to return the rows of `C` and `D` based on the top two values in `B`.

For some reason the index of `grp_df` is multilevel and includes both `A` and the original index of `ddf`.

I was hoping to simply `reset_index()` and drop the unwanted index and just keep `A`, but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
```

Here is a simple example reproducing the error:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

grp_df = ddf.groupby('A')[['B','C']].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns=['B']), meta={
    "B": 'f8', "C": 'f8'})

# Print is successful and results are correct
print(grp_df.head())

grp_df = grp_df.reset_index()

# Print is unsuccessful and shows error below
print(grp_df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Found approach for solution [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2929).

Following code now allows for `reset_index()` to work and gets rid of the original `ddf` index. Still not sure why the original `ddf` index came through the groupby in the first place, though

```
meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['B', 'C'], dtype=int, index=pd.MultiIndex([[], []], [[], []], names=['A', None]))
grp_df = ddf.groupby('A')[['B','C']].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns=['B']), meta=meta)

grp_df = grp_df.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```